# How can I write the following equation in WinEdt?

Tags: math-mode

I try to write the equation shown in the pic using WinEdt but I failed. I need to centre it with a number refer to the equation, any idea?
I try the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cccc}
$\ U^*_{n}$ \\
$\ I^*_{n}$ \\
$\ R^*_{n}$ 
\end{array}
%
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Not sure that your question is particular to Winedt?

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: @cmhughes: it is, by metonymy ;o)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that either with  `kbordermatrix` or with `blkarray`. Note in the latter method, a `block` environment has to end with a `\\`. Also the brackets may be a bit short, so we may have to use `\bigstrut`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \kbordermatrix{&U_n & I_n & R_n\\
    U_n^* & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
    I_n^* & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
    R_n^* & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
  }
  \qquad
  \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
    &U_n & I_n & R_n \\
    \begin{block}{c<{\hspace*{-0.5em}}[rcc]}
      U_n^* & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
      I_n^* & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
      R_n^* & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\bigstrut[b]\\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all people who give comments I write it using bordematrix command as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
\[\bordermatrix{
            & $\ U_{n}$ & $\ I_{n}$ & $\ R_{n}$\cr
$\ U^*_{n}$ & a_{1,1}   & a_{1,2}   & a_{1,3}\cr
$\ I^*_{n}$ & a_{2,1}   & a_{2,2}   & a_{2,3}\cr
$\ R^*_{n}$ &  a_{3,1}  & a_{3,2}   & a_{3,3}}\]
\end{equation}
```

I found the answer in the following book: 
The Art of LATEX
by: Helin Gai

Comment: You don't need to use all these `$…$`.

Comment: Seems you have two accounts! Please visit the help page to contact the stackexchange staff to merge them ...

Comment: I have only this account